# onaddstream event not called

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I use WebRTC to connected 2 Chrome Browsers. I create `offer` on the first and send it via `signalR` to second client like this :

```
function initiate_call() {
callerPeerConn = new RTCPeerConnection(peerConnCfg);
callerPeerConn.ontrack = function (event) {
    console.log('caller recived new stream');
    remoteVideo.srcObject = event.streams[0];
    console.log(event);
}
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: true })
    .then(function (stream) {
        localVideo.srcObject = stream;
        for (const track of stream.getTracks()) {
            callerPeerConn.addTrack(track, stream);
        }
        return callerPeerConn.createOffer();
    })
    .then(
    function (offer) {
        var off = new RTCSessionDescription(offer);
        callerPeerConn.setLocalDescription(
            new RTCSessionDescription(off),
            function () {
                // invite to video chat
                console.log('send offer');
            },
            function (err) {
                console.log(err.message);
            }
        )
    });
}
```

When my second browser getting `offer` he use `setLocalDescription` and try to create `answer` than send it to caller like that :

```
function accept_send_answer(){    
calleePeerConn = new RTCPeerConnection(peerConnCfg);
calleePeerConn.ontrack = function (event) {
    console.log('callee accept offer and got streams');
    remoteVideo.srcObject = event.streams[0];
}
calleePeerConn.setRemoteDescription(offer)
    .then(function () {
        return navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: true });
    })
    .then(function (stream) {
        localVideo.srcObject = stream; 

        for (const track of stream.getTracks()) {
            calleePeerConn.addTrack(track, stream);
        }
        return calleePeerConn.createAnswer();
    })
    .then(function (answer) {
        // sending answer

        console.log("sending ansfer");
        var remote_streams = calleePeerConn.getRemoteStreams();
        var local_streams = calleePeerConn.getLocalStreams();

        console.log("callee remote streams");
        console.log(remote_streams);
        console.log("callee local streams");
        console.log(local_streams);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    });
}
```

## UPD

After I changed my code, following the advice of a respected @jib, my local and remote streams on both sides was successfully added to RTCPeerConnection object. I successfully obtain following messanges in console : `caller recived new stream` and  `callee accept offer and got streams` as well. Last problem is - why this code not working :

```
calleePeerConn.ontrack = function (event) {
    console.log('callee accept offer and got streams');
    remoteVideo.srcObject = event.streams[0];
}
```

video not played.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, `addStream` and `onaddstream` are deprecated, and won't work in other browsers. Use [addTrack](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/addTrack) and [ontrack](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/ontrack) instead.

Second, timing.

You're calling `peerConn.createOffer()` before `peerConn.addStream(stream)` so tracks are not picked up.

Same with `peerConn.createAnswer()` before `peerConn.addStream(stream)`.

Lastly, mixing callbacks and promises confuses the order of things here. Try:

```
const peerConn = new RTCPeerConnection(peerConnCfg);
peerConn.ontrack = function (event) {
  alert('new stream added! ' + event.streams[0]);
}
```

```
function initiate_call() {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: true})
    .then(function (stream) {
      localVideo.srcObject = stream;
      for (const track of stream.getTracks()) {
        peerConn.addTrack(track, stream);
      }
     return peerConn.createOffer();
    })
    .then(function (offer) {
      // signaling and invite
      return peerConn.setLocalDescription(off);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      console.log(err.message);
    });
}
```

```
function accept_send_answer(offer) {
  peerConn.setRemoteDescription(offer)
    .then(function () {
      return navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: true});
    })
    .then(function (stream) {
      video.srcObject = stream;
      for (const track of stream.getTracks()) {
        peerConn.addTrack(track, stream);
      }
      return peerConn.createAnswer();
    })
    .then(function (answer) {
      //signaling to caller and send answer
      return peerConn.setLocalDescription(answer);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      console.log(err.message);
    });
}
```

Note that your code (and my reply) still lack critical pieces: ice candidate exchange, and you're not showing your `setRemoteDescription(answer)` code to complete the negotiation loop.

Note that most examples tend to use the same JS on both sides, like e.g. this [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jib1/ges8uqom/) using iframe postMessage for signaling.

Comment: My `MediaStream`s length always: 1. Is it normal ?

Comment: Thank for you help, just edited Question, could you check now?

Comment: This Code - not worked. How to bind `RemoteStream` and <Video/> ?

Comment: Should I make exchange `icecandidates` before start ?

Comment: Please don't fix the question as it invalidates the answer and its value to others who come across it. @Сергей I added a link to a working example. hope that helps.

Comment: @jib ok, got it. unfortunately js-fiddle code not worked in my case. - https://imgur.com/a/cFPuEO7

Comment: could you clarify, is the Caller must get `iceCandidates` from Callee and Callee must get `iceCandidates` from Caller ? Only after this exchange remote stream can be used in local <video> ?

Comment: @ИльяШульц ah, sorry that's a Chrome [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=740501). I've updated the fiddle to not rely on `negotiationneeded`. Try it now. Yes you must exchange ice candidates to connect.

Comment: @jib Yes, they are working fine now. thank you. i'll try to repeat icecandidate exchange.